# Omni Channel Flow Error: The queue isn’t valid for this object type

Tags: visual-workflow, servicecloud, omnichannel, queue

My flow is using an action called "Check Availability for Routing" to retrieve information about 3 queues like this:

[image]

I configured each of the action elements selecting the Queue, and then storing the outputs retrieved in separated text variables:

[image]

However, when I debug this flow, I get this error saying "The queue isn’t valid for this object type."

[image]

Since this is an omnichannel flow, it requires me to add the **recordId** variable, so I added it as a text variable available for input. When I execute the flow, I paste into the recordId variable **a case Id** (whatever I find). I have confirmed that all of these queues are configured to use the Case object

[image]

However, even when using a Case id, the issue still persists.

If anyone knows how to fix this problem, I'd be very grateful.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. All the queues that will be checked for the 'Chat' service channel need to implement the 'Chat Transcript' object .

That means that I had to go to setup > queues > select my queue > click on edit, and then add the 'Chat Transcript' object to the list of available objects for the Queue.

Once I did that, the flow worked.

Special thanks to Tom Basset who answered this question on the Trailblazer community:
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54V00007RIOCmSAP